# storing response from paginated api in rust

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am trying to call a paginated API with the code below. When I call it without the `next-token` (i.e. no loop), I can count the number of balances i.e. response.balances.len().

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Algoholder {
    balances: Vec<Balance>,
    #[serde(rename = "current-round")]
    current_round: i64,
    #[serde(rename = "next-token")]
    next_token: Option<String>,
}

async fn get_algorand_data() -> i64 {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let mut response;
    let mut current =
        "http://mainnet-idx.algonode.network/v2/assets/2751733/balances?currency-greater-than=0"
            .to_string();
    loop {
        response = client
            .get(&current)
            .header("x-api-key", &env::var("ALGOD_TOKEN").unwrap())
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
            .header("pragma", "public")
            .send()
            .await
            .unwrap()
            .json::<Algoholder>()
            .await
            .unwrap();

        if let Some(next) = &response.next_token {
            current = format!("{}&next={}", "http://mainnet-idx.algonode.network/v2/assets/2751733/balances?currency-greater-than=0", next);
            println!(
                "{}",
                format!("{}&next={}", &env::var("ALGOD_URL_1").unwrap(), next)
            )
        } else {
            println!("Balances in loop : {}", &response.balances.len());
            break;
        }
    }
    println!("Number of accounts {}", response.balances.len() as i64);
    response.balances.len() as i64
}
```

However, I am getting 0 for when i evaluate the balance in the loop and out of it. I would appreciate any assistance with this.

```bash
http://mainnet-idx.algonode.network/v2/assets/2751733/balances?currency-greater-than=0&next=UQIOTCZOKI3VIDIF7IY72DIZUCGLRSMHY65NCQHJ3IG6ZJPWTCG7PXMAUQ
http://mainnet-idx.algonode.network/v2/assets/2751733/balances?currency-greater-than=0&next=777ILN5AAYHZ7RHSFZOAYVJHEJSRZRJCCXEAUMMHIY7AGR7ZMDTAU52BII
Balances in loop : 0
Number of accounts 0
```

Comment: The last request returns an empty balance sheet (try it in a browser). However your `response` is overwritten instead of appended to each other, hence once the loop exits, `response` contains 0 balances. You likely want to make a vector of `responses` and append your `response` to it each iteration.

Comment: I dont understand, the second response `http://mainnet-idx.algonode.network/v2/assets/2751733/balances?currency-greater-than=0&next=777ILN5AAYHZ7RHSFZOAYVJHEJSRZRJCCXEAUMMHIY7AGR7ZMDTAU52BII` returns a response i just curled it to verify

Answer (score 1):

The issue with my code is that I was not storing the results of the loop anywhere.

I created a Vector of the object and push them into it.

Here is the updated function that works:

```rust
async fn get_algorand_data() -> i64 {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let mut response;
    let mut current =
        "http://mainnet-idx.algonode.network/v2/assets/2751733/balances?currency-greater-than=0"
            .to_string();
    let mut holders: Vec<Algoholder> = Vec::new(); // Initialise Vector here
    loop {
        response = client
            .get(&current)
            .header("x-api-key", &env::var("ALGOD_TOKEN").unwrap())
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
            .header("pragma", "public")
            .send()
            .await
            .unwrap()
            .json::<Algoholder>()
            .await
            .unwrap();
        holders.push(response.clone()); // push them here
        if let Some(next) = &response.next_token {
            current = format!("{}&next={}", "http://mainnet-idx.algonode.network/v2/assets/2751733/balances?currency-greater-than=0", next);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    let mut sum = 0;
    for entry in &mut holders {
        println!("The Entry is  {:?}", entry.balances.len());
        sum += entry.balances.len();
    }
    sum as i64
}
```